# The Word "Siri" in the Playstore 'forbidden'?

Tags: android, google-play

Im asking myself for a long time. Is the word Siri in the Appname of an App in Playstore forbidden or not ? There are some Apps that are called like that example : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=andy.xml ,  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magnifis.parking or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluetornadosf.smartypants . How is this possible ? I thought its against the rules of the Developer Console of Google am I right ?`Would my app been banned if I use this word ? Thanks for your answers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of an app distribution channel, not programming. Please see [this Meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for the guidelines for what is and is not on-topic about distribution channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the question shouldn't be here but I already typed an answer. You really could have found this answer in minutes, so next time search on Google first.

You cannot publish anything with copyright or [trademark infringements](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2986098?hl=en) if you do your app will be removed if it is reported or discovered. It also leaves you open to being sued by the [trademark owner - Apple](https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/trademark/appletmlist.html). Even implying a link to the original item can leave you open to [impersonation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2985822) lawsuits. If your app is removed and Google consider it a serious breach, your account will be [terminated](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) entirely.

So the answer is, it could be serious, but it depends how you use it. In any case just looking at your links above and the similar apps section shows there are already dozens of apps of varying quality offering 'siri-like services'. Ask yourself is it even worth risking your account by adding another copycat app to get lost in the results for that keyword unless yours is something truly special?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I actually couldn't find it in google but ok now.

Comment: Alright I knew what I was looking for so it makes it easier, I just search something like "google play developer policy copyright" so try the same or similar if you have more issues